# How to deal with Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3 NuGet package?

Tags: nuget

- The `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3` nuspec file claims a dependency on `WebGrease.1.5.2`
- WebGrease.dll from that NuGet package has the Assembly Version of `1.5.2.14234`
- However, `System.Web.Optimization.dll` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3` depends on `WebGrease` with the Assembly Version of `1.5.1.25624`

So the nuspec is wrong. It prevents consuming the package without explicit binding redirects, because the dependency tree restored by NuGet is plain wrong.

Am I missing anything or Microsoft published a bad NuGet package?